# Parsing content of VisualXhtmlEditor with Razor

Tags: razor, c1-cms

I read this page

http://docs.composite.net/XSLT/XSLTFAQ?q=How+to+parse+an+XHTML+value+from+a+data+field+used+in+XSLT+functions%3f

but I can not make it to work with the Razor syntax.

I understand I should first call the MarkupParser function like this

```
@Html.C1().Function("Composite.Xslt.Extensions.MarkupParser")
```

But then what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the "MarkupParser" XSLT Extension when in Razor - use this:

```
@Html.Raw(htmlString)
```

Comment: Aaargh! I feel a bit stupid. I use @Html.Raw() in a lot of other pages. Guess it's friday...